# Is there any way to access modify css classes without useRef() in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, quill

I have a react component of an editor and I'm trying to change the position of a tooltip according to pixel bounds ... however, I'm not exactly rendering the tooltip myself and it's happening inside the component.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import Quill from 'quill';
import 'quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import 'quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';
import './styles.css'

interface Props {
  content: string;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

const Editor2: React.FC<Props> = ({ content, onChange }) => {
    const editorRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const toolbarRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<string>("lol");

    useEffect(() => {
        if (editorRef.current) {
            const editor = new Quill(editorRef.current, {
                theme: 'bubble',
                modules: {
                    
                    toolbar: [
                        ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
                        ["blockquote", "code-block"],
                        [{ header: 1 }, { header: 2 }],
                        [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
                        [{ script: "sub" }, { script: "super" }],
                        [{ indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }],
                        [{ direction: "rtl" }],
                        [{ align: [] }],
                        ["clean"],
                    ],
                },
            });

            editor.on('text-change', () => {
                onChange(editor.root.innerHTML);
            });

            editor.root.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            editor.root.style.width = '100%';
            editor.root.style.color = 'black';


            editor.root.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
                const selection = editor.getSelection();
                if (selection && selection.length > 0 && toolbarRef.current?.style) {
                    const bounds = editor.getBounds(selection.index, selection.length);
                } else {
                    // toolbarRef.current.style.display = 'none';
                }
            });
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div className='ql-tooltip' style={{position: 'absolute'}} ref={toolbarRef} />
            <div style={{width: '768px', marginTop: '15rem'}}>
                {/* <div ref={toolbarRef} className="editor-toolbar">
                <button onClick={handleLink}>Link</button>
            </div> */}
                <div ref={editorRef} />
                {selected}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Editor2;
```

I want to set the `top` of `ql-tooltip` to a certain bound, but I don't know how to attach the useRef to that element (it's coming from within the react quill library)

is there anyway to modify this and access that top attribute?

Comment: If you have a `ref` on the main container of the editor can you not go down the list with `editorRef.current.children....` until you find your tooltip?

Answer (score 1):

Nick.

Yes, you can access the top attribute by using a ref and adding an event listener to the editor. Quill exposes a getBounds function, which allows you to calculate the pixel bounds of the current selection. You can use that data to set the top value of the toolbar ref to the calculated position of the selection.

```
editor.root.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
                const selection = editor.getSelection();
                if (selection && selection.length > 0 && toolbarRef.current?.style) {
                    const bounds = editor.getBounds(selection.index, selection.length);
                    toolbarRef.current.style.top = `${bounds.top}px`;
                } else {
                    toolbarRef.current.style.display = 'none';
                }
            });
```

***Another Alternative***

I think you can access the Quill instance directly from the editorRef.current reference and then use the getBounds() method to get the coordinates of the selection. From there, you can set the position of the toolbar accordingly .

```
// Get the Quill instance from the editorRef
const quill = editorRef.current && new Quill(editorRef.current);

// Get the bounds of the selection
const selection = quill.getSelection();
if (selection && selection.length > 0) {
  const bounds = quill.getBounds(selection.index, selection.length);

  // Set the position of the toolbar
  toolbarRef.current.style.top = `${bounds.top}px`;
} else {
  // Hide the toolbar if there is no selection
  toolbarRef.current.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: yes but i'm not able to attach toolBar ref to `ql-toolbar` div — right now toolBar ref isn't referencing anything. i thought having a dummy toolbar would allow me to style it with bounds but it doesn't do anything.